# May I ask questions about obscene language here?

Tags: support

And should I somehow mask these words?

I don't want to break local rules, but haven't find such a restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you may.

Don't use obscene words in the title, in censored or uncensored form. The question might become hot and its title would end up in the sidebar on the other sites.

You may use any obscene words in the post body, provided that they are germane to the topic on the discussion and are not used as insults or to convey your own emotions.

If you are using obscene words in the post body, don't mask or censor them, or replace them with euphemisms.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that concerns learning Russian language, "good" or "bad" parts - it doesn't count.
I don't agree (a very rare thing!) with Quassnoi on not having any obscene words in title - I'd rather say it's not a rule but a kind requirement. However, yep, it would be nice thing to do.

We even have a dedicated tag -[https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)